# Application based on feedparser

Tags: python, feedparser

Is there an application based on python library `feedparser` that works under Ubuntu and shows scheduling and storage of feeds?

thank you

Comment: Can you provide some detail as to what you mean by scheduling and storage of feeds? Are you referring to the gathering and aggregation of feed content (i.e. when I get feeds, when I publish feeds) - or storage in the sense of databases that facilitate search.. Your question is somewhat vague.

Comment: by scheduling I mean : Design of repetitive downloading of content (checking for new content) by storage I mean: How is the downloaded information stored (flat storage, sqlite database), what data structures are used. What is good to use what is not good (low performance etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one of these?

- [Planet](http://www.planetplanet.org/)
- [Venus](http://intertwingly.net/code/venus/)
- [rawdog](http://offog.org/code/rawdog.html)

Comment: could you please write here some files from those projects showing the scheduling and storage?